# Does the $T$ in the Lagrangian $L=T-V$ depend only on the generalised velocities?

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism

Does the kinetic energy term only depend on the generalised velocities (q') or could it depend on the generalised coordinates too?

Comment: Hint: write the kinetic energy in polar coordinates.

Answer (score 3):

Even leaving aside [the subtlety that Andrew discusses](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/301552/520) we can address this.

Take as a specific example a bead of mass $m$ on a straight, light wire free to rotate in a plane. Generalized coordinates: the angle $\theta$ of the wire and the radial distance $r$ of the bead.
$$ T = \frac{1}{2} m \left[(r \dot{\theta})^2 + \dot{r}^2\right] $$
One of the coordinates appears undifferentiated in the kinetic term.

Answer (score 2):

Generically, it is impossible to separate $L$ (or $H$) into $T$ and $V$. For example, it is the case for a particle moving in the magnetic field, where $\vec{p}$ must be replaced by $\vec{p}-\frac{e}{c}\vec{A}(x)$, where $A$ is a vector potential generically depending on the coordinates, so the "kinetic" term in the Hamiltonian becomes $T=\frac{1}{2m} \left(\vec{p}-\frac{e}{c}\vec{A}(x) \right)^2$.

There are may be more trivial cases with $T$ depending on the coordinates. For instance, if a particle moves on a non-flat manifold with the metric $g_{ij} (x)$, the "kinetic" term has the form $T=\frac{1}{2m} g_{ij} (x) \frac{\mathrm{d}x^i}{\mathrm{d}t} \frac{\mathrm{d}x^j}{\mathrm{d}t}$.

Comment: Would this not be in a Hamiltonian formslism though?   You need L to define the generalized momentum.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero Sure. The second example doesn't refer in any way to Hamiltonian formalism -- it is written in terms of velocities $\frac{\mathrm{d}x^i}{\mathrm{d}t}$. The first example being rewritten in the Lagrangian formalism will contain the coupling $\frac{\mathrm{d}x^i}{\mathrm{d}t} A_i(x)$. Is it kinetic or potential term?

Comment: Interestung question.  I would say potential actually, but agreed that for this example one must jerry-rig the Lagrangian with additional pieces to reproduce the equations of motions.